# Function that returns two values on rows as per condition on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
**Num Bool Square Cube**
0   1   T   1   1
1   2   T   4   8
2   3   T   9   27
3   4   F   NaN NaN
4   5   F   NaN NaN
5   6   F   NaN NaN
```

```
def power(num):
    return num**2, num**3
```

I am unable to apply *power* method to above dataframe columns 'Num' and 'Bool' to get 'Square' and 'Cube'

Comment: Not clear on what you'r asking for ?

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: Sorry for unclear post. First ever though. So the dataframe that is present is the expected output. Input will be the dataframe with first two columns. I want to have this output dataframe using power method and only for rows where Bool is 'T'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I expect your problem is returning two values in your function and have them map into your data frame columns. You can solve that with applying `pd.Series` after your initial `apply`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Num': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'Bool': [True, True, True, False, False, False]
    }
)


def power(num, bool):
    if bool:
        return num**2, num**3
    
    
df[['s', 'q']] = df.apply(lambda row:
    power(row['Num'], row['Bool']), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)


   Num   Bool    s     q
0    1   True  1.0   1.0
1    2   True  4.0   8.0
2    3   True  9.0  27.0
3    4  False  NaN   NaN
4    5  False  NaN   NaN
5    6  False  NaN   NaN
```